# A easy way to pass parameter back and forth in every page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

I want to pass an id back and forth in every page.  I can not use session, application variables and database since I want it is base on page.  Hidden field if a form exists or url concatenation are what I can think about.

Is there an easy way to get and send this id without manually adding it to url or hidden field in every page?  For example, use a master page or a url rewriting method.

Comment: Are you using Web Forms? Which version of ASP.NET?

Comment: May be use hidden field in the master page? Also, create an utility class to get/set that...

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Yes.  It is Web Forms with version 4.5.  Thanks

Comment: @mshsayem, I thought about the master page and an utility class.  But I don't know how to do that.  Can HttpContext class be used in the utility to concatenate the id?

Comment: You can pass a page reference to that class; then use this to get that variable: `page.Master.FindControl("hiddenFieldId")`

Comment: Why don't you want to use session or cookie variables? Seems like a natural way to handle this.

Comment: @JoshuaCarmody user can open multiple tabs or windows in different page.  In this case, the id should be different with different page.   Using session or cookie will mess up, since session and cookie are not page based on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea:

Place a hidden field in the master page:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdCrossPageValue"/>
```

Use this extension method to get/set that value from every page:

```
public static class Util
{
    public static string GetCrossPageValue(this Page page)
    {
        if (page == null || page.Master == null) return null;
        var hf = page.Master.FindControl("hdCrossPageValue") as HiddenField;
        return hf == null ? null : hf.Value;
    }
    public static void SetCrossPageValue(this Page page, string value)
    {
        if (page == null || page.Master == null) return;
        var hf = page.Master.FindControl("hdCrossPageValue") as HiddenField;
        if (hf != null)
        {
            hf.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
this.SetCrossPageValue("my cross page value");
var crossPageValue = this.GetCrossPageValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

setup a public string value in your master page

```
Public partial class MasterPage:System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string myValue
    {
        get{return "Master page string value" ;}
        set {}
    }
}
```

Access the property in your child page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPage mp = (MasterPage) Page.Master;
    myLabel.text = mp.MyValue
}
```

Comment: this may be what I am looking for.  I will verify this.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer it with the request url as parameter.
example
In page 1 you redirect to page 2 with parameter Test

```
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?param1=Test");
```

In page 2 you get it like:

```
if (Request.QueryString["param1"] != null)
  var param1 = Request.QueryString["param1"];
```

Comment: in this way, I have to find and edit every page.  That is the last approach I can do.  I have hundreds of pages needed to pass the id.

Comment: Yes don I understand, But looking at the working options,It's a solution. I hope you find a better way with less effort